# Why is my Amazon Sagemaker SDK not working with my AWS ModelPackage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use ModelPackage, in a sagemaker pipeline. The problem is that my ARN comes out of a lambda as follows:

```
model1_step_latest_model_fetch = LambdaStep(
    name="model1_fetchLatestModel",
    lambda_func=func,
    inputs={
        "model_package_group_name": model_1_package_group_name,
    },
    outputs=[
        #output_param_1
        LambdaOutput(output_name="ModelPackageArn", output_type=LambdaOutputTypeEnum.String),   
    ],
)
```

the output of the lambda is the input to the ModelStep and enters in the following way

```
model1 = ModelPackage(
    model_package_arn = model1_step_latest_model_fetch.properties.Outputs["ModelPackageArn"],
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    role=role,
)

model1_step_create_model = ModelStep(
    name="model1_CreateModel",
    depends_on=[model1_step_latest_model_fetch],
    step_args=model1.create(instance_type='ml.m5.large', 
                            accelerator_type = 'ml.eia1.medium',
                        )
)
```

then I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-78b6597cc2bf> in <module>
     12     depends_on=[model1_step_latest_model_fetch],
     13     step_args=model1.create(instance_type='ml.m5.large', 
---> 14                             accelerator_type = 'ml.eia1.medium',
     15                         )
     16 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    275             if run_func.__name__ in ["register", "create"]:
    276                 self_instance.sagemaker_session.init_model_step_arguments(self_instance)
--> 277                 run_func(*args, **kwargs)
    278                 context = self_instance.sagemaker_session.context
    279                 self_instance.sagemaker_session.context = None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/model.py in create(self, instance_type, accelerator_type, serverless_inference_config, tags)
    495             accelerator_type=accelerator_type,
    496             tags=tags,
--> 497             serverless_inference_config=serverless_inference_config,
    498         )
    499 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/model.py in _create_sagemaker_model(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1720             container_def["Environment"] = self.env
   1721 
-> 1722         self._ensure_base_name_if_needed(model_package_name.split("/")[-1])
   1723         self._set_model_name_if_needed()
   1724 

AttributeError: 'Properties' object has no attribute 'split'
```

## does anyone know what is going on? if I enter the ARN in ModelPackage manually as string it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A ModelStep's `step_args` takes one of two things: either a `model.create()` call or a `modelpackage.register()` call. You are passing it a `modelpackage.create()` call.

Because that function isn't intended to be run by pipelines, the SDK is trying to do a string operation on a `Properties` object and throwing the error you see.

I'd suggest reviewing the [ModelStep documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html#step-type-model). If your goal is to create a Model using the ModelPackage information you fetched with your Lambda, that might look something like this:

```
model1_step_latest_model_fetch = LambdaStep(
    name="model1_fetchLatestModel",
    lambda_func=func,
    inputs={
        "model_package_group_name": model_1_package_group_name,
    },
    outputs=[
        # NOTE: this Lambda returns the ModelDataUrl for the model package, not the model package ARN
        LambdaOutput(output_name="ModelDataUrl", output_type=LambdaOutputTypeEnum.String),   
    ],
)

model1 = Model(
    image_uri=pytorch_estimator.training_image_uri(), # set correct image
    model_data=model1_step_latest_model_fetch.properties.Outputs["ModelDataUrl"],
    sagemaker_session=PipelineSession(),
    role=role,
)

model1_step_create_model = ModelStep(
    name="model1_CreateModel",
    depends_on=[model1_step_latest_model_fetch],
    step_args=model1.create(instance_type='ml.m5.large', 
                            accelerator_type = 'ml.eia1.medium',
                        )
)
```